# Commutativity of linear operators

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let    $$ T: V \rightarrow V$$    be a linear operator on a vector
>   space $V$ over a field $F$ and with a basis    $$ B = (\mathbf{u}_{1},
>  \cdots, \mathbf{u}_{n}).$$    Let    $$ f(x), g(x) \in F[x]$$    be
>   polynomials. Then
>
> $$ f(T)g(T) = g(T)f(T).$$

Does that mean if i am given a linear operator $T:V \to V$, and another map $T - \lambda I_V$, i can say both maps commute with each other because of the above theorem.

I say : $$f(x) = x,~~~ g(x) = x - \lambda$$
Then $$f(T) = T,~~~ g(T) = T - \lambda I_V$$

and hence they commute. Moreover, if $g(x) = (x-\lambda)^n$, then $h(T) = (T-\lambda I_V)^n$ and subsequently by the above theorem, we have $$T \circ (T- \lambda I_V)^n = (T - \lambda I_V)^n \circ T$$

Can anyone clarify this? I am working on the proof of Jordan normal form.

Comment: Yes, $T$ commutes with powers of $T-\lambda I$.

Comment: Yes, but is my line of logic correct in showing that they commute ?

Comment: Have a little confidence!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The linear operators commute if they are the polynomials of     the same operator. So yes .What you said is true.

Comment: How do we prove that linear operators commute if they are the polynomials of the same operator?